# Field Value validation failed in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/key/developerApplication]

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Getting Error : Field Value validation failed in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/key/developerApplication]

On the API : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A534asdasd3323,user:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3A342342332,entity:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A234243,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)

Getting Response :

{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Field Value validation failed in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/key/developerApplication]",
"status": 403
}

Can anyone help me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you go to LinkedIn app settings, you will see

"Client ID: (letters and numbers)"

This is what you seem to have used but this is **not** the one you need. Instead, you want the old, numeric ID, which you will see in the URL of the app settings:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/<the integer id of your
app>/settings
```

So, it will go like this:

```
...developerApplication:urn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A<the integer id of your app>...
```